# How to do online single word recognition with background noise in Java

Tags: java, cpu-word, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I'm aware of some of the general topics around Sphinx 4 recognizer for Java, and maybe parts of that system could be used for this purpose.

I want to have a system waiting for a specific word to be spoken, maybe with background noise, and with other words spoken between. Is there a packaged way to do this in Java, or a good simple method for this?